# passing multiple parameters via object and "automatically" creating variables

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Javascript and trying to learn best practices. Recently I learned about destructuring and I'm using it to pass multiple parameters to another function like this:

```
function test() {

let parameter1 = 'something';
let parameter2 = 'something else';
let parameter3 = 'this';

  doSomething({
    parameter1,
    parameter2,
    parameter3})
}

function doSomething(parameters){
  let {parameter1,
  parameter2,
  parameter3} = parameters;

Logger.log(parameter1);
Logger.log(parameter2);
Logger.log(parameter3);
}
```

I wonder if there's an easier way to recreate the variables?
I mean, I can essentially skip the "let" part by referencing the variables like:
`Logger.log(parameter.parameter2)`

But I'm wondering if there's some sort of `unpack(parameters)` function that would be the equivalent of the `let` in the doSomething function.

The reason I'd want to do this is because the list of parameters is long, and I'm wondering, e.g. if there're 30 parameters, is there a shortcut to use instead of having to "re-define" all 30 parameters.

Comment: You can just destructure the one that's needed for your Logger function from your parameters like: `function doSomething({parameter2})`

Answer (score 0):

Just destructure the parameter in the function parameters:

```js
// You didn't include the Logger implementation in your post, so I just create one
const Logger = {
  log: (info) => console.log(info),
};

function test() {
  let parameter1 = 'something';
  let parameter2 = 'something else';
  let parameter3 = 'this';

  doSomething({
    parameter1,
    parameter2,
    parameter3,
  });
}

function doSomething({ parameter2 }) {
  Logger.log(parameter2);
}

test();
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized my question needed a bit more clarity. I'm trying to see if there's a way to save a whole lot of typing/cut-n-pasting.

Comment: If you don't have that many arguments, you can just use normal parameters through which arguments are passing by order.

Comment: I do have a lot of arguments. That's why I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this, instead of retyping/copy-pasting all the variables again.